# RradioButton GroupBox in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

At run time I populate the values in DataGrid. dropdownlists,numeric,bool,text.

Is it possible to have a group of radio buttons ?

How can to do it ? how to add a groupbox so that one of them is selected at a time?

if I don't use a DataGridView, what is another suitable View ?

PS. not using xaml,wpf. classic windows forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datagridview will not be suitable for this kind of combination, therefore, it's best if you use the flow layout control and that should help with organising the lay out.

I think you can't put a groupbox in a datagridview component, it's not made for that I think.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own `DataGridViewCell` with painting logic and handling click events. Long time ago I did something like that, maybe it will be useful for you:

http://pastebin.com/nh4PfPPS

I paint check box and 2 radio buttons and save their positions to handle clicks.

I did not create column for it, because I needed to mix cell types, so just in place where I was adding rows and needed that cell I did:

`row.Cells[0] = new DataGridViewControlCell();`

I would not say it is the best way, but hey worked for me. Good luck :)

Comment: That sounds good. However, I need them at runtime with reflections, also need them to be editable with one click, in this case it will be 1 activate, 1 select, 1 deactivate. i want to have few rows, each modifiable by one click :+s